# Understanding call stack

Tags: c++, callstack

I have the following method:

```
std::string MaterialLayer::getName()
{
    std::string idfMaterialName = this->material->getName() + std::string("-") +   cea::wstring2string(StringConverterHelper::toString((static_cast<double>((floor(this->thickness*1000)) / 10))));

    return idfMaterialName;
}
```

That is called through the following piece of code:

```
bsm::MaterialLayer * ml = this->o_bsm_material_layer;
std::string name = ml->getName();
```

When I do step into debugging on the second line ( where ml->getName() is called ), I entered the following method :

```
void Material::setName(const std::string &name)
{
    this->name = name;
}
```

But I cannot understand why it is called given that the called method is a setter on the Material class, while the original call is on a getter of the MaterialLayer class!!!

I specify that:

- I have already rebuilt all the solution
- all is compiled in Debug modality
- Visual Studio is 2010
- the parameter name of setName() is  at the calling instant, this leads to the throwing of an exception later, and the need of this debug activity stemmed from the exception thrown, in order to understand why...

Comment: looks impossible, suggest re-compile the entire codebase and retry

Comment: Note that it's apparently calling `setName` on the `Material` class, not `MaterialLayer` which is what you're calling `getName` on. I also suggest recompiling. If that doesn't help, look at what `name` is set to when entering `setName`, and see if that helps.

Comment: I have already rebuilt all the solution, therefore all the projects included in it, but nothing changed, the strange call still happens... :(

Comment: is the code you are debugging compiled in debug mode?

Comment: @JosephMansfield if you mean looking at the value of the parameter name of setName(), it is to value <BadPtr>, thus leading also to an exception later, from which the need of a step into debugging has stemmed...

Comment: Is `bsm::MaterialLayer::getName` getting actually called when you execute this line ? What is in `name` in `Material::setName` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. yes, all is compiled in Debug mode, x64, Visual studio 2010

Comment: @MichaelWalz no, the block of getName is never stepped through. From the line ml->getName(), the execution jumps directly to the method Material::setName(), this is the strange... :(

Comment: Ìt looks as if `this->o_bsm_material_layer` is corrupted or more likely that it points actually to an object of type `Material` rather than `MaterialLayer`. Is suppose `getName` is virtual and hence the call to the wrong function.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, getName of MaterialLayer is (wrongly) virtual. I'll immediately fix this design error, but honestly I cannot see how virtuality can create such a mess in this case...

Comment: @davide please show the declarations of `Material` and `MaterialLayer`, especially the parts where `setName` and `getName` are declared. Also show the inheritance between them if any.

Comment: re the plea for suggestions, i suggest that you drop the "get" prefix. in c++ it's just verbosity. also, just use `std::to_string`. and third, make yourself a formatter rather than doing concatenation. concatenation is generally quadratic time in number of items, + ugly. finally, **don't forget `const`**.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for your contrib but I think it is OT.

Comment: @MichaelWalz indeed, now without virtual the method getName() is correctly called. Tnx a lot, indeed an incredible mess to me it seemed...

Comment: @davide watch out, there is probably another problem and removing `virtual` may actually just hide the real problem.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, probably there is another problem somewhere else. May I ask you to have a look pls at the following other post of mine, on the same issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442543/understanding-watch-window-in-visualstudio-2010

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can imagine such a thing can happen is with an example like this:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void FuncA() ;
} ;


class B
{
public:
  virtual void FuncB() ;
} ;


void A::FuncA()
{
  printf("FuncA\n") ;
}

void B::FuncB()
{
  printf("FuncB\n") ;
}

int main()
{
  A a ;
  B *b ;

  b = (B*)&a ;

  a.FuncA();    // calls A::FuncA
  b->FuncB();   // b points actually to an A object
                // calling B::FuncB now actually calls A::FuncA

  return 0 ;
}
```

I suppose a similar thing happend in your program.

Comment: Wow, but how this is possible given that the two methods have different names ??? (FuncA is different from FuncB !!)

Comment: @davide because `FuncA` and `FuncB` are both virtual functions the program calls them by looking up the virtual function table pointer which is the first item in the object. It then calls the function pointer which is the first entry in that table since each class only has one virtual function. Because Michael has casted the pointer to a different type the function which actually gets called is different to the one implied by the source code. I do think it is highly unlikely that this is the case you are experiencing though.

Comment: @sjdowling Tnx for the explanation, I supposed indeed that it was passing through the function address / pointer and not the function names, but I did not know about a virtual function table pointer... Tnx again to all for your kind explanations!