# Understanding Watch window in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: c++, debugging, watch

I cannot understand what the part of the object within square bracket means ( [bsm::Material] see pic below ). I would expect the object ml of type MaterialLayer to be composed only of a part of type Object (base class) + two fields thickness and material (a pointer to Material).

So, what is the part between square brackets, shown by Visual Studio 2010 in its Watch window?

[image]

Here is the definition of the Material, Object, and MaterialLayer classes:

```
class Object
{

public:
    // Methods
};


class Material : public Object
{
    int type;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Property *> properties;

public:
    // Methods
};


class MaterialLayer : public Object
{
    double thickness;
    Material * material;

public:
    // Methods
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `ml` is declared as `bsm::MaterialLayer*`, but a pointer of type `bsm::Material*` was assigned to it by typecasting:

```
bsm::MaterialLayer *ml;
bsm::Material *foo;
ml = (bsm::MaterialLayer *)foo;
```

This does not generate a typecast error in compile-time but will almost certainly lead to errors like nonsense values in `thickness` and `material`.

However, since they both share a common parent, Watch shows its real child in square brackets.